# How to detect/handle touch events on curved regions?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm starting on a native iPad app (we can assume iOS 4.3+ if necessary) where I need to have a series of curved regions that bump up against each other.

[image: A series of curved regions stacked on top of each other]

I'd love some advice about the best way to handle this.

One thought I had was to use a WebView and just have a JPG and an HTML image map but I'd really prefer to use some kind of native UI element that supports curves.

Any recommendations?

Comment: create bezier paths, triangulate them (as concave shapes) then just check if point of touch is in any of the triangles.

Comment: Eimantas, that sounds interesting.  Could you flesh out the concept of that a little for me?

Comment: You don't have to triangulate your bezier path, `UIBezierPath` already has a `containsPoint:` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a problem something like this. To resolve it, we created a black and white mask in Adobe Illustrator. You'll need to do this for each and every distinct region that you want.

Next, we exported this file. I can't remember the file export option, but basically you get a text file that has a load of path data that includes lines, bezier curves, etc.

We then took this file and wrote an importer that parsed it and created a CGPath.

The final stage is the easy bit. You get your touch point from UITouch and do a CGPathContainsPoint call.

Here's some pseudo code for this:

1. Skip lines until we get to one with "1 XR". That's the 
   indication of something meaningful in the subsequent line.
2. Split the line into an array of components using a separator of " ".
3. The last component of the line is the action. If it's "m" it's a path move, if it's "C", it's a bezier curve, and if it's "L" it's a line.
4. If it's a "Y" or a "V" then you need to get the previous line's components and parse as follows:

(a) Component count includes action, so we need to reduce this. E.g. 274.5600 463.6800 m
(b) If this line has four coordinates and the previous one has two, then it's a point node to a bezier node. Figure your bezier curve points as follows:

```
    cp1x = previous line's components object at index 0
    cp1y = previous line's components object at index 1
    cp2x = this line's components object at index 0
    cp2y = this line's components object at index 1
    x = this line's components object at index 2
    y = this line's components object at index 3
```

(c) Otherwise if this line has four coordinates and the previous line has four or six coordinates, figure as follows:

```
    cp1x = this line's components object at index 0
    cp1y = this line's components object at index 1
    cp2x = this line's components object at index 2
    cp2y = this line's components object at index 3
    x = this line's components object at index 2
    y = this line's components object at index 3
```

Where cp is "control point". So you have control point one and control point two with their respective x and y coordinates.

Comment: This is sounding like a good approach for me.  I'm pretty sure we have the regions I'm going to be working with in Illustrator already and I'd love to see some of your code.

Comment: will do. Let me double check with my old boss that he doesn't mind me posting some excerpts!...

Comment: Anything you can share would be fantastic.  Thanks!

Comment: I've got the bezier creation & touch handling code mostly figured out.  I'd be especially curious to hear about your process for exporting from Illustrator.

Comment: Hi Mark I added some pseudo code. I realised that I most likely can't give the code verbatim without getting myself into trouble! So I hope this helps. Let me know if you have any specific questions and I will do my best to help out. Have you had a chance to look at the exported illustrator file yet?

Comment: xj1200, thanks for the pseudo-code, it's very helpful.  I actually found an objective-c class which dates an SVG d="" attribute and turns it into a UIBezierPath.  So I took your approach of exporting from Illustrator to SVG and now I have a lovely set of clickable regions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create bezier paths that each represent separate regions (by doing `lineToPoint` or similar functions).

```
UIBezierPath *p1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path1 lineToPoint:somePoint];
[pointArray1 addObject:NSStringFromCGPoint(somePoint)];
// create lots of points and close p1 path
```

Then find some triangulation algorithm for concave shapes that would turn each bezier path to an array of triangles (i.e. instead of storing array of bezier path point coordinates you'd store array of triangles' coordinates (array of array of points). Algorithm and explanations can be found in any game development forum or even on [GameDev of stack exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9680/polygon-triangulation-algorithm).

Repeat the bezier path creation and triangulation for each region.

Then having these arrays it's just a matter of simple iterations to check if certain point of interest is in one of these triangles.

**update** seems that @omz comment renders my answer useless, hence it's just a matter of creating bezier paths and calling method on each of them .)