# CGPath from image

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, calayer, mask, cgpath

I need to create mask based on image (any possible shape). I need to:

1. Create CALayer with CGPath as a proper mask
2. Call [UIView.layer setMask: with layer above ]

So main big question is how to set CGPath based on black-white image? Or is it possible to place mask **directly** from image?

Thanks!

---

Example image of a mask: 
[image: example mask]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to create your image with an alpha channel. According to `CALayer`'s mask property documentation:

> An optional layer whose alpha channel is used as a mask to select
>   between the layer's background and the result of compositing the
>   layer's contents with its filtered background.

So the layer you want to use as mask needs an alpha channel. If you want to use an image to create such a channel, the image itself needs to have an alpha channel. So you would need to copy the black and white mask you posted above into the alpha channel of an image. The color of that particular image is ignored. You then load the image, set a layers contents to it and use that layer as a different layers mask. Something around this:

```
UIImage* imageWithAlphaChannel = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alpha.png"]; // Won't work with jpg
CGImageRef cgImageWithAlpha = [imageWithAlphaChannel CGImage];
CALayer* maskingLayer = [CALayer layer];
maskingLayer.contents = (id)cgImageWithAlpha;

//Assume viewToBeMasked is the view, who's layer needs to be masked
CALayer* layerToBeMasked = viewToBeMasked.layer;
layerToBeMasked.mask = maskingLayer;
maskingLayer.frame = layerToBeMasked.bounds;
//Alternativly use: viewToBeMasked.layer.mask = maskingLayer;
```

Coded in the browser, excuse systactical errors.

Storing all your masks as png files might blow your app size. You could store the masks as jpgs and create the appropriate alpha version at runtime using the CoreGraphics drawing functions. But that is another question.....

Comment: That's great, man! I have one additional question for you. How to make a final step and set UIView's layer as a layerToBeMasked. Setting [view.layer addSublayer:layerToBeMasked] isn't working. I was trying to do layerToBeMasked = view.layer but isn't working neither. Should I do something extra to make it working? Thanks!

Comment: You will not need to set any sublayer here. You will set the mask property of the layer. I have updated the code above to better reflect that.

Comment: It wasn't working for me somehow. I had to set a maskingLayers's frame and its ok now. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, you are right. You'll need to set the frame. I forgot about that. Updated the code above.

Answer (score 3):

Very similar issue *I think* to something I did a while back. Basically, you'll need to export the file from Adobe Illustrator then run a routine to convert that file into a CGPath.

You'll find how to do it in my answer to this question:

[How to detect/handle touch events on curved regions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431742/how-to-detect-handle-touch-events-on-curved-regions/7432136#7432136)

Comment: when you say mask, do you mean "a black and white version of the image"?

Comment: Yes. I will create those images by myself so it can be described in any way. Basically what I am trying to do is [view.layer setMask: _CALayer containing image or CALayer with path built from image_ ] . Is it understandable?

Comment: ah, ok I think I'm starting to get it. You'll need to do this manually I'm afraid. Basically adding your mask layer as a sublayer of the view you want to mask. Your mask would of course have the alpha set appropriately so that the masked image would be visible where appropriate.

Comment: Sorry for bothering, but I am not getting it. So can I set image as a mask? What do you mean "do it manually"? Describe every shape as a bunch of points... ? I cant just say "hey, take this image as a mask-pattern" ?

Comment: Just to be sure - image shouldn't be masked. UIView should. On black pixels of the image.

Comment: Looks like I was wrong about the mask property. I'll leave my answer above in case it's useful for anything and vote up tonklon's...