# iOS: Adding an outline/stroke to an image context with a transparent background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

The images that goes through here are PNGs of different shapes with a transparent background. In addition to merging them (which works fine), I'd like to give the new image a couple of pixels thick outline. But I can't seem to manage that.

(So just to clarify, I'm after an outline around the actual shapes in the context, not a rectangle around the entire image.)

```
+ (UIImage *)mergeBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage withOverlayingImage:(UIImage *)overlayImage{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(backgroundImage.size, NO, backgroundImage.scale);
    [backgroundImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, backgroundImage.size.width, backgroundImage.size.height)];
    [overlayImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(backgroundImage.size.width - overlayImage.size.width, backgroundImage.size.height - overlayImage.size.height, overlayImage.size.width, overlayImage.size.height)];

//Add stroke.

    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return result;
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Markus

Answer (score 0):

If you make a CALayer who's backing is set to a CGImage of your image, you can then use it as a masking layer for your layer that requires an outline[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433821/cgpath-from-image). And once you've done that, you can render your layer into another context, and then get another UIImage from that.

1. // edit: Something like what's describe in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433821/cgpath-from-image) answer.